# MySQL select with multiple many to many joins causing very slow query

Tags: mysql, join, many-to-many, mysql-slow-query-log

Using the following table structure:

#### Items (~20,000 records)

- item_id

#### Properties (~30 records)

- property_id

#### Item_properties (~40,000 records)

- id
- property_id
- item_id

A user can choose to filter items by a number of fields in the `items` table itself, and can also choose any number of `properties` that the item must have. The search needs to choose an item with *all* properties, not just one of them. I'm currently using the format

```
SELECT item.field...
FROM items
INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip1 ON ip1.item_id=item.item_id and ip1.property_id=3
INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip2 ON ip2.item_id=item.item_id and ip2.property_id=4
INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip3 ON ip3.item_id=item.item_id and ip3.property_id=5
INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip4 ON ip4.item_id=item.item_id and ip4.property_id=6
etc...
WHERE item.something_else='words'
GROUP BY item_id
```

I have also tried, as a way of specifying search purely by WHERE rather than by JOIN

```
SELECT item.field...
FROM items
WHERE item.something_else='words'
and item_id IN (select item_id from item_properties where property_id=3)
and item_id IN (select item_id from item_properties where property_id=4)
and item_id IN (select item_id from item_properties where property_id=5)
and item_id IN (select item_id from item_properties where property_id=6)
etc...
```

However this approach seemed, if anything, to take even longer to query the set. With about 4 properties chosen query time is about 4-5s, much more and the queries tend to get killed or bring the MySQL server down altogether.

As far as I am aware all the _id fields are indexed on each table, being the primary keys of their respective tables too.

Are there ways to improve the query or might I need to limit the number of options that can be queried?

Comment: INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip1 ON ip1.item_id=item.item_id and ip1.property_id IN(3,4,5,6)

Comment: Thanks; that works to create an __OR__ style search, where an item must have at least one of the properties. I'd actually like the item to have _ALL_ the properties chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use post aggregation filtering if you want all property_id

```
SELECT item.field
FROM items
INNER JOIN item_properties AS ip1 ON ip1.item_id=item.item_id and  
and ip1.property_id IN(3,4,5,6)
WHERE item.something_else='words'
GROUP BY item.field
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT property_id )=4
```

4 is the number of  property_id IN(3,4,5,6)

Comment: This seems to work well; query time isn't substantially altered using the `HAVING` and it's faster than adding more indexes to the multiple join or sub query approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need an index on `item_properties`:

```
create index idx_item_properties_2 on item_properties(item_id, property_id)
```

Comment: Is that different functionally from the item_id and property_id already being indexed on that table?

Comment: I've created that and it does speed up the multiple join approach used above. Still 4.5s for the largest possible query but significantly better than crashing out MySQL. I think for efficiency of the actual query I may go with the answer that uses `HAVING` but this is helpful.

Comment: @M1ke . . . Why do you have the `group by item_id`?  If you have no duplicate properties, then this should be unnecessary (and you might find that removing it gives you another performance boost).

Comment: @M1ke . . . A composite index is different from two separate indexes on the columns.

Comment: Wouldn't the group be necessary to prevent one row for each item/property combination? I.e. the same item information would be present for each property that the item had, if using the joins?

Comment: @M1ke . . . If there are no duplicate matches in the `join`, then you will get only one row per item.  And, you will only get a row for an item when all joins succeed (because you are using `inner join`).